# equation of the circle which passes through two points and the chord joining them making an angle $\theta$ in the major segment of the circle

Tags: circles

I am facing trouble finding out the equation of the circle which passes through two points ($x_1,y_1$) and ($x_2,y_2$) and the chord joining ($x_1,y_1$) and ($x_2,y_2$) making an angle $\theta$ in the major segment of the circle.

I thought of transforming the equation to polar coordinates and taking the line joining ($x_1,y_1$) and ($x_2,y_2$) as the initial line and ($x_1,y_1$) as the origin.  The equation of the circle in the new system would be then $$r^2-2ar\sin(\theta-\theta')=0$$
But I am facing difficultly restoring it to the origin coordinate axes and hence converting it in cartesian form.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.Thanks.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your two known points be $A$ and $B$.
Let the center of the circle (which you have to find) be $P$.
You are given that $A$ and $B$ are both on the circle and 
you are given the angle $\angle APB = \theta$.
(Or perhaps it is $\angle APB = 2\pi - \theta$,
or perhaps $\angle APB = 2\theta$,
depending on what is meant by "making an angle $\theta$
in the major segment of the circle."
In any case, in this answer I'll take $\angle APB$ as known 
and will not use the symbol $\theta$.)

Let $M$ be the midpoint of segment $\overline{AB}$. Then
$\triangle AMP$ and $\triangle BMP$ are congruent right triangles.
The hypotenuse of each triangle, $PA$ or $PB$,
equals the radius of the circle,
one leg is equal to $\frac12(AB)$, and the other leg is equal to $MP$.
Note that since $A$ and $B$ are known, the length $AB$ is easily found.

We also know that $\angle APM = \frac12 \angle APB$.

So we have a right triangle with one leg ($\frac12(AB)$)
and the angle opposite that leg ($\frac12 \angle APB$) are known.
Therefore we can find the length of the other leg of the triangle
by using trigonometry.

So now we have the distance $MP$.
We also know $P$ must be on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB}$.
With that information we can find the coordinates of $P$;
there are two possible results, depending on which direction
you go along the perpendicular bisector.
The easiest way to find one of the possible locations of $P$
may be to take $AB$ and $MP$ as
the hypotenuses of two right triangles whose legs are parallel to the
$x$ and $y$ axes; the two triangles are similar, so the legs of one
are easily computed when you known its hypotenuse $MP$ and all three
sides of the other triangle.

At this point in the procedure you have the $(x,y)$ coordinates of
the center of the circle,
and there are several ways you could find its radius.
Writing the equation of the circle is simply a matter of
plugging this information into the well-known formula.

Comment: Please consider adding diagrams to this answer,

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(x_1,y_1)$, $B(x_2,y_2)$ and $C(x,y)$ be a point on the major arc $AB$.

By simple geometry of circle,

\begin{align*}
  \angle AOB &= 2\angle ACB \\
  2\pi-\theta &= 2\angle ACB \\
\end{align*}

Applying cosine law in $\Delta ABC$,
\begin{align*}
  \cos \angle ACB &= \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab} \\
  -\sin \frac{\theta}{2} &=
  \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)}
       {\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}}
\end{align*}

which is the equation of major arc $ACB$.

**Squaring both sides gives two circles.**

> For example, $\theta=270^{\circ}$, $A=(1,1)$, $B=(-1,-1)$ we have
>
> \begin{align*}
>   x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4-8x^2+8xy-8y^2+4 &= 0 \\
>   (x^2+y^2+2x-2y-2)(x^2+y^2-2x+2y-2) &= 0
> \end{align*}

[image]

Comment: How is angle AOB =$2\pi-\theta$

Comment: $\angle AOB$ is the the angle of minor arc while $\theta$ is angle of minor arc.